# Flutter Android App executing shell command with root privileges

Tags: android, flutter, root

I am learning Flutter in order to make a personal app for my **already rooted device** that will save me from running 1-2 scripts in [Termux](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page) (terminal emulator for android).

The problem I am facing is that those 2 scripts need root access because they must retrieve the result of a "ls" inside a root filesystem folder (in particular a "/data/data/" folder of another app).

Currently I made the UI and now I need to populate all the Cards objects, each containing one Text object computed on the basis of the names of the files retrieved by that "ls" command I was talking about.

I tried using https://pub.dev/packages/root but it is not working properly, I mean it works for implementing a Root Check, which I did, because in the settings of the app I wanted to show if the app could actually ask for root access.
Using this simple function, in combination with a FutureBuilder I achived what I wanted:

```dart
Future<bool> checkRoot() async {
    bool result = await Root.isRooted();
    return result;
  }
```

Then I tried to exec a simple shell command, both with the help of this root package (Failing) and then with the code snippet I wrote:

```dart
  Future<String> getFilePaths() async {
    // List all files in the current directory in UNIX-like systems.
    var result =
        await Process.run('ls', ['-l', 'myfolder']);

    return result.stdout;
  }
```

But as you can imagine the result here was null, and checking result.stderr I discovered that the command is executed by user and not root as the folder can't be found.

So my question is, how should I proceed? Can I actually run a command in root mode from my flutter app? Do I have other options?

Thank you.

Comment: Write native code.

Comment: @ProblematicDude Could you please expand? I'm new to flutter and android programming in general. Are you suggesting to write that part specifically in Java/Kotlin? Then would it be possible to wait for a result of a native code process and only then display it with Flutter? Thanks